# Need Clear concept of Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

Attached code : http://speedy.sh/xTEp8/XYZFrameworkDemo.zip

I have create a framework name ABCFramework.framework having my Constant.h file where i put my MACRO used in my code.
For Ex:

```
#define     WEBURL @"www.google.com/api"
```

Not i have following question.

1)
Please explain how do i distribute my ABCFramework.framework so it can be used in both simmulater and Iphone device,as till now i have to use both seperately with example code in which i want to use it.

2) 
Please if a developer import my ABCFramework.framework in his code and he want to change the Constant.h WEBURL with his own WEBURL how to do it?

```
#define     WEBURL @"www.google.com/api" //SDK URL

#define     WEBURL @"www.yahoo.com/api" //USER URL TO BE ADD?
```

On adding aggregate target and run script

```
xcodebuild -target ABCFramework -sdk Debug-iphonesimulator
xcodebuild -target ABCFramework -sdk Debug-iphoneos
rm -rf "$SRCROOT/products" mkdir -p "$SRCROOT/products/ABCFramework"
lipo -create "$SOURCE_ROOT/build/Release-iphonesimulator/ABCFramework" "$SOURCE_ROOT/build/Release-iphoneos/ABCFramework" -o "$SOURCE_ROOT/products/ABCFramework/ABCFramework"
cp -r "$SOURCE_ROOT/build/Release-iphoneos/include/ABCFramework" "$SOURCE_ROOT/products/ABCFramework/include"
```

I am getting this error /

```
xcodebuild: error: SDK "Debug-iphonesimulator" cannot be located.
xcodebuild: error: SDK "Debug-iphoneos" cannot be located.
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/xxxxxxxx/build/Release-iphonesimulator/ABCFramework (No such file or directory)
cp: /Users/xxxxxxxx/build//build/Release-iphoneos/include/ABCFramework: No such file or directory
```

**NOTE: My project in which i create ABCFramework is XYZFrameworkDemo**

Answer (score 2):

1) To create a Universal framework that works on Simulator and device you have to build them separately and then use the lipo command to merge them. You do this by creating a Aggregate target and building the code once in simulator and once for device. You add a Run script phase to the aggregate target to build both simulator and device version which will go into their respective folders and then merge them using lipo command.

```
xcodebuild -target ABCFramework -sdk iphonesimulator
xcodebuild -target ABCFramework -sdk iphoneos
rm -rf "$SRCROOT/products"
mkdir -p "$SRCROOT/products/ABCFramework"
lipo -create "$SOURCE_ROOT/build/Release-iphonesimulator/ABCFramework" "$SOURCE_ROOT/build/Release-iphoneos/ABCFramework" -o "$SOURCE_ROOT/products/ABCFramework/ABCFramework"
cp -r "$SOURCE_ROOT/build/Release-iphoneos/include/ABCFramework" "$SOURCE_ROOT/products/ABCFramework/include"
```

2) You cannot change the macros in the framework after its built. You have to provide a api or a exported variable to set this property from the app that's integrating your framework.

Comment: where to get lipo ?? please share screenshot if possible

Comment: Its should be part of the Xcode command line tools. Install Xcode command line tools if you don't have it using `xcode-select --install`

Comment: thnx i have downloaded Xcode command line tools how to open it please?

Comment: Create an aggregate target in your project and add a Run script phase to that target as specified above. You might have to change the target names a bit depending on your config

Comment: means , in the project in which i create framework i need to create aggregate target  right?

Comment: There are problems in your command. Why is the -sdk Debug-iPhoneSimulator? Check my command and update the names of the project

Comment: please check edit question with sample code attached

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102669/discussion-between-iphonemaclover-and-pradeep-k).